# Как разместить сайт на хостинг, написанный на Java, с помощью framework Spring

Tags: java, spring

Есть готовый хостинг на https://www.ukraine.com.ua/, и есть сайт написанный на Java.Мой сайт запускается на локальном сервере, но я хочу чтоб он запускался на хостинге.Как это сделать?

Comment: Вам нужно на сервер поставить Tomcat, собрыть `war` файл из проекта спринга и поместить его в нужную папку Tomcat-а. Если хостинг у вас не VPS/VDS то ничего не получится, т.к. нельзя туда свои программы ставить, вроде.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сейчас попробую

Comment: @ЮрийСПб чем встроенный Tomcat в Spring хуже чем отдельно поставленный tomcat?

Comment: @Antonio112009, я привёл тот способ который сам использую. Да, вроде как можно и иначе, но я так не пробовал, ничего сказать не могу на сей счёт.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а я не пробовал ваш способ) Поэтому и интересуюсь.

Comment: @Antonio112009 избыточностью, если на сервере нужно использовать больше одного web-приложения.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev понял